# How to get the difference between two csv by Index using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need to get the difference between 2 csv files, kill duplicates and Nan fields.
[image: cite_id frame]

[image: df frame]

I am trying this one but it adds them together instead of subtracting.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df,cite_id]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)[['id','website']]
```

`df` is main dataframe
`cite_id` is dataframe that has to be subtracted.

Comment: please provide dataframe minimal info in question as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this efficiently using 'isin'

```
df.dropna().drop_duplicates()
cite_id.dropna().drop_duplicates()
df[~df.id.isin(cite_id.id.values)]
```

Or You can merge them and keep only the lines that have a NaN

```
df[pd.merge(cite_id, df, how='outer').isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I want to note here that this answer was posted after mine and no different. Wonder why you pick this one. @Billy

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
df1 = df1.dropna().drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.dropna().drop_duplicates()
df = df2.loc[~df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
```

Comment: please explain what happens here and what is df1 and df2 related to id only or id and url DF?

Comment: df1 is the dataframe after you read the first csv, df2 is the dataframe for 2nd csv.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two dataframes as one, after that you can remove all dupicates

```
df1 

    ID  B   C   D
0   A0  B0  C0  D0
1   A1  B1  C1  D1
2   A2  B2  C2  D2
3   A3  B3  C3  D3

cite_id
    ID  B   C   D
4   A2  B4  C4  D4
5   A3  B5  C5  D5
6   A6  B6  C6  D6
7   A7  B7  C7  D7

pd.concat([df1,cite_id]).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep=False)
```

Out:

```
    ID  B   C   D
0   A0  B0  C0  D0
1   A1  B1  C1  D1
6   A6  B6  C6  D6
7   A7  B7  C7  D7
```

Comment: it merges all availble data from df into cite_id for 9000 raws it has. What I need is get new DataFrame with data difference between the two.

Comment: can your tell me, what you want difference, do you want to exclude the ids , which are already part of df , is that  @BillyJhon?

Comment: I want to exclude ids from df that are listed in cite_id.

Comment: @BillyJhon i just edited the code for your requirement  of excluding ids listed in cite_id